# export all rows of a html table with pagenation to excel sheet

Tags: html, excel, activex

I have one html table where pagenation is used. So it displays 10 rows once. When i am exporting my table to a excel, only the first 10 rows which are there in the html table are getting exported. I want all the rows to be exported. Please suggest some way.

Below is the code I am using.

```
function exportToExcel(){
 var mytable = document.getElementById("tlb_setup");
    var rowCount = mytable.rows.length;
    var colCount = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("th").length;
    var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
   ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("........\\requestsInExcel.xlsx"); 
    var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
    ExcelApp.Visible = true;

    //var ExcelSheet = ExcelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1");

    //ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                str = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[j].innerText;
            }
            else {
                str = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerText;
            }
            ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = str;
            //Workbook.SaveAs("........\\requestsInExcel.xlsx");
        }
    }
    //ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
    ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.columns.autofit;
    ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;
    DisplayAlerts = true;

}
```

Comment: @RedFilter can u plz help on this?

Comment: @jarlh ++ any idea about it.